# encode json object params in httpurlconnection

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection, encode

I want post some parameters to server with httpurlconnection in android,my data is an nested JsonObject , and i must encode it first but it's wrong because i receive status error from server, this is my encode function and Jsonobject:

```
    private static String encodeParams(JSONObject params) throws Exception   {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));
      }
    return result.toString();
    }
```

my nested json:

```
JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();
postDataParams.put("name", "Manjeet");
postDataParams.put("email", "manjeet@gmail.com");

JSONObject par = new JSONObject();
par.put("class", "a");
par.put("family", "aray");

postDataParams.put("par", par);
```

Comment: i think the second jsonobject encode wrong

Comment: log your error please, i think that you have to recursively encode your object

Comment: my error handle from server side, they say the information that you post is wrong , how can recursively encode my object ?

Comment: ok, could you put the result of your encoded url for the above exemple ?

Comment: i send data for an test url that in php code say just print evry thing that post and in android i receive this : {"par":"{\"class\":\"a\",\"family\":\"aray\"}","email" : "manjeet@gmail.com","name" : "Manjeet"}

Answer (score 1):

Construct a URI from the output, only encoding the characters `?#/`
 which is a lot easier than your loop

You can use URI's, which produce a different output and result
The following sample

```
new URI("http", "host.com", "/path/", "key=| ?/#ä", "fragment").toURL();
```

produces the result [http://host.com/path/?key=%7C%20?/%23ä#fragment](http://host.com/path/?key=%7C%20?/%23%C3%A4#fragment). Note how characters such as ?&/ are not encoded to allow for the URI Query string
(Copied from the API)

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure about this code, since i've never worked with JSONObject, but i'll try to show you the **idea** :

Create a method which returns all the properties of an object (including the nested one) :

```java
Map<String, String> jobjectToMap(JSONObject jo) {
   Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>;
   Iterator<String> itr = jo.keys();
   while(itr.hasNext()){
        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = jo.optJSONObject(key);//this will returns null if the value is not a JSONObject from https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf242/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject-java.lang.String-
        if(value != null) { //nested object
           properties.putAll(jobjectToMap(value));
        } else {
           properties.put(key, jo.get(key)); //primitive one
        }
   }

   return properties; 
}
```

Create another method which transforms the map to an url

```java
public String queryParams(Map<String, String> params)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
    if (params.size() > 0) {
     queryString.append('&');
    }

    // Convert the params map into a query string.
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet())
    {
        String encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8");
        String encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8");

        queryString.append(encodedKey);
        queryString.append('=');
        queryString.append(encodedValue);
    }

    return queryString.toString();
}
```